# why the x before +"the number is"

Tags: javascript

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>

<p>Click the button to loop through a block of code five times.</p>
<button onclick="myFunction()">Try it</button>
<p id="demo"></p>

<script>
function myFunction() {
  var x = "";
  for ( var i = 0; i < 5; i++ ) {
      x = x + "The number is " + i + "<br>";
  }
  document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML=x;
}
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

I understand what it returns but I don't understand the x before each statement.

```
x = x + "The number is " + i + "<br>";
```

Comment: I think this might help http://en.wikiversity.org/wiki/Introduction_to_Programming/Variables#Variables - 'X = X + 1 ... Looking at this assignment as a mathematical equation, it makes absolutely no sense—no value is equal to itself plus one. But we're not talking about mathematics here. While it may look like an equation, this is a variable assignment that states "retrieve the value of X, add one, and store the result back in X." '

Answer (score 2, accepted):

x is a variable which is going to grow over the loop.

The line:

```
x = x + "The number is " + i + <br>
```

just appends the line 
"The number is " + i + end of line
to the current value of x.

Think of this line as:

```
var y = x + "The number is " + i + <br>
x = y
```

At the end of the loop, x is worth all that:

"The number is 0
The number is 1
The number is 2
The number is 3
The number is 4
"

If instead of x = "", you had x = "Hello, ", then the final result would be:

"Hello, The number is 0
The number is 1
The number is 2
The number is 3
The number is 4
"

Comment: can you show work on that for me? i understand what it does but why? x=" " "the number is" then i then line break
where does it restart?

Comment: Let's take it step by step: at the beginning, x = "". After the first iteration of the for loop, x is worth "The number is 0<br>". The second loop iteration does: x = "The number is 0<br>" + "The number is 1<br>". So at the end of the second loop iteration, x = "The number is 0<br>The number is 1<br>". The third loop does: x = "The number is 0<br>The number is 1<br>" + "The number is 2<br>", and so on...

Comment: It's not a problem of where does it restart, as you can see in @GHL answer he use "" to make you understantd that x becomes a variable that **contain** all that text that you keep appending. You should know that '+' operator for strings in javascript has this property of concatenation, this said, you **don't** eliminate the text previously assigned, there's no substitution, just appending :)

Answer (score 0):

```
x = x + "The number is " + i + "<br>";
```

appends to the current value of `x` the specified text and stores it back in x.

Comment: but if i specify that x="hello" instead of " " then it only returns "hello the number is" on the first line and after that it no longer includes hello

Comment: @Jordan This is because IF you wrote x = "Hello"...
THAT particular line is OUTSIDE the FOR/NEXT LOOP so it ONLY gets executed ONCE and not multiple times like the TEXT INSIDE the FOR/NEXT LOOP